# jquery simple drop down content issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to code a simple jQuery drop down nav using `slideDown` and `slideUp` function, but it doesn't seem to be working properly, please find the css and js code below:

```
.programsnav ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:120px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.programsnav ul li:hover{
    border-bottom:dashed 1px #fcfe93;
}
.programsnav ul li span{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:930px;
    top:42px;
    left:-371px;
    background:#fcfe93;
    color:#161527;
    padding:10px 15px 15px 15px;
}
.programsnav ul li span a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-right:dotted 1px #161527;
    color:inherit;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#downloadnav li').hover(function() {
            $('span', this).slideDown(100);
        }, function () {
            $('span', this).slideUp(100);       
     });
});
```

**html**

```
<ul id="downloadnav">
<li>Movies<span><a href="#">Movie1</a><a href="#">Movie2</a></span></li>
<li>Songs<span><a href="#">Song1</a><a href="#">Song2</a></span></li>
<li>Games<span><a href="#">Game1</a><a href="#">Game2</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Its keeps animating if i do mouseover on span>a, please help, thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/UaWh6/

Comment: @JonathanSampson Sampson try mouseover on movies, songs and games, and you will notice the issue, its keeps animating.

Comment: I did mouse over those, and it was fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: This is a terrible way to make a dropdown menu. Use nested ul instead. And you example is full of errors. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dt2Jd/3/

Comment: @JonathanSampson i have tried both chrome and firefox.it may be issue of css

Comment: @seoppc Are you saying whenever you put your mouse over the `span` element it flickers?

Comment: @JonathanSampson can you try this one jsfiddle.net/dt2Jd/3  ?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Please suggest correct approach for this.

Comment: @seoppc I've taken the liberty to work up an example for you below.

Answer (score 1):

To be completely honest, there are several things wrong with this code. For starters, this markup is not conducive to a drop down menu navigation. Typically those follow this convention:

```
<ul id="downloadNav">
    <li>Movies
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Movie 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Movie 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Songs
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Song 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Song 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Games
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Game 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Game 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Additionally, the styling has the element off to the right, rather than "dropping down". I've taken the liberty to work up a quick example and hope that you can study it to better understand a more sensible approach to this problem.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LRBqJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery 1.7.2**

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#downloadnav li').hover(function() {
            $('span', this).stop().slideDown(100);
        }, function () {
            $('span', this).stop().slideUp(100);       
     });
});
```

---

### CSS

```
ul#downloadnav {
    position: relative;
}
ul#downloadnav  li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:120px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
ul#downloadnav  li:hover{
    border-bottom:dashed 1px #fcfe93;
}
ul#downloadnav  li span{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:930px;
    top:0px;
    margin-top: 41px;
    left:-371px;
    background:#fcfe93;
    color:#161527;
    padding:10px 15px 15px 15px;
}
ul#downloadnav  li span {
        display: none;
}
ul#downloadnav  li span a{
    display:none;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-right:dotted 1px #161527;
    color:inherit;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

---

### HTML

```
<ul id="downloadnav">
<li>Movies<span><a href="#">Movie1</a><a href="#">Movie2</a></span></li>
<li>Songs<span><a href="#">Song1</a><a href="#">Song2</a></span></li>
<li>Games<span><a href="#">Game1</a><a href="#">Game2</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Works fine in my FF

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RuZYu/)** is the working demo.

Comment: not working, it now works only once and hides until i don't refresh the page.

Comment: check the demo. BTW which browser r u using?